# What does 'mothercanuckers' mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, offensive-language

First of all, sorry if it is offensive (I think it somewhat is).
I was going through http://bleacherreport.com/articles/424590-the-funniest-promos-and-moments-in-wwe-history#page/20

> The Rock owned everyone by calling the
>   Canadians mothercanuckers

I heard him saying this in the video but what does that mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

["Canuck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canuck) is a slang word for someone from Canada. It's not usually considered offensive — sometimes it's even affectionate (and Canadians use it themselves in quite a few contexts). It's a [regional nickname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regional_nicknames), like "Yankee" and other terms.

It is likely that "The Rock" simply took the (offensive) word "motherfuckers", and replaced "fuck" with the rhyming "Canuck" (replaced "f" with "can"), to make the word "mothercanuckers".

Thus "mothercanuckers" is a label combining "motherfuckers" and "Canuck" (or, to use Wikipedia's favourite word, it's a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of the two). It combines an offensive word and a slang nickname.

The humour (if any) comes (I guess) from this combination (of the offensive with the innocuous) — of having used an ordinary nickname to suggest overtones of offensiveness without actually using an offensive word, thus fulfilling the duties of trash-talking presumably expected of the character.

Comment: Or to put it simply: While Canuck is not offensive, "Mothercanucker" would likely be used in a derogatory/offensive manner.

Comment: Are even Canadians are now offensive to some? Who could be offended by a Canadian, eh?

Comment: @Atømix: I'm not sure "Mothercanucker" is derogatory or offensive: IMO, it's just a nonce word that suggests/recalls an offensive word, without being one itself (and is even mildly humorous).

Comment: I believe that the preferred racial slur for Canadians is "frostback" - as per Scott Thompson :).

Comment: Like the word it’s based on, it could be used either approvingly or derogatorily.  When the Maple Leafs play beautiful hockey: “Whoo, those are some fast mothercanuckers!”  When customs agents have confiscated your beer: “Stupid jobsworth mothercanuckers!”

Comment: @PLL Maple Leafs? Beautiful hockey? Pfft.

Comment: @user1150 At least  PLL spelled *Maple Leafs* (the team name) correctly.