# What do you call the eating of frogs?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Herpivory"?  "Ranophagy"?  Hurry, I need to mock a French friend.

Comment: The OALD says that [Frog](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/frog) is an offensive word for French people... Why eating a frog?

Comment: mocking is against the rules here!! (only joking =) have fun!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess I should know !!!

You could create some neologism such as
 - amphibiophagy  ( ἀμφίβιος => *both lives* + φαγεῖν => *to eat*)
 - batrachiophagy ( βάτραχος => *frog* + φαγεῖν => *to eat*)
 - anuraphagy ( αν => without + ουρά => tail + φαγεῖν => *to eat*) credits @Malvolio.

Comment: [anuraphagy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anura)?

Comment: @Malvolio, yes this is nice as well.

Comment: @Malvolio, I stole it from you and added it in the answer ;-)

Comment: If you'll only eat true frogs, you're a batrachiophage; if you'll down a toad or two as well, you're an anuraphage; if you'll even dine upon newts and salanders, you're an amphibiophage.  *Bon appetit*.

Comment: +1 for *batrachiophagy*, as in "βατραχομυομαχία". But are you certain about the translitteration of χ with “chi” even if it's followed by “o”? I'd go with *batraco-*, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: @Agos: if it's coined in a classical manner from the Greek roots it should be batrachophagy. But since the form of "batrach-" most familiar to people is the family name Batrachia, "batrachiophagy" is a natural coinage.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that would be a **ranaphagy**, from family *Ranidae* (true frogs), most of the edible ones being genus *Rana*.

I think calling him a **ranophage** sounds better though.

[Here's](http://www.clovegarden.com/ingred/reptile.html) a link mentioning edibility of a couple of species. It ain't just the Frogs wot eat frogs. Apparently them damned Yankees eat even more! (or maybe I should say 'damned Confederacy Southerners')

Comment: rana is a Latin word, phagy comes from Greek.  I tried not to mix up.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: If I'm to be criticised, at least I'll know it was from an expert! I didn't even know (or check). But I seem to recall that such lexical chimeras are not without precedent. Anyway, just to drive home the advantage, I'll also mention that the question is tongue-in-cheek to start with. Besides, if @Malvolio's French pal posts here asking how to answer the taunt, you'll be a shoo-in Top Answer for a withering riposte!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I was miles away of intending to be rude. I hope it is clearer now.  And you're right, there *are* chimeras like this.  In this kind of situation it is always possible to say **rana-vore** and you're consistent !

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: I hope I've noticed you enough on EL&U to know you're unlikely to be rude. I on the other hand am prone to appear so, unintentionally. And sometimes I actually do get tetchy. I suppose **ranavore** really should be the definitive answer. But *-phage* to me suggests more primitive life-forms like *bacteriophages*, whereas even humans are *omnivores*. If you're gonna insult the guy, talk him right down the food chain!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- My French friend *started it*!  Specifically, I had written "Bon nuit, mon fille." and she corrected it to  "Bonne nuit, ma fille" and added some choice remarks about "you anglophones and your lack of gender-specific articles."  Which I think should strike close to home for everyone here (except maybe Alain).

Comment: @Malvolio: Sacre bleu! Lack of adequate gender indicators in our degenerate excuse for a language led me to assume your friend was a 'bullfrog'. For God's sake don't tell her I'm now thinking 'cow-frog'!

Comment: While mixing greek and latin is not a great idea, there is at least one such word that caught on without problems: television.

Comment: @Agos: not to mention 'automobile'.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I think cars are really Erinacevores (hedgehog eaters). But that's only because I don't know of a Latin suffix for "flattener".

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- *platysficere* perhaps?