# When and why did the number reading order change

Tags: numbers, reading, old-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [19th century English texts occasionally use germanic-style number words, such as “four-and-twenty”. When did this fall out of use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/19th-century-english-texts-occasionally-use-germanic-style-number-words-such-as)

In Arabic and even in several European languages (e.g. German) one reads the lower ranks digit first.

- German => 24 is read *vierundzwanzig*
- Arabic => 24 (٢٤) is read *Arba3aton wa 3echroun*" (أربعةٌ وعشرون).

In Old English you find the same order:

- Old English => 24 is read *féower ond twentig*.
- Present Day English => twenty four.

So it looks like the reading order has changed at some point.  The question is: why and when ?

Comment: Uhm... I think the Germanic languages would be more relevant to your question... A quick search on my own revealed that also in Danish they say 4-20, which should be _firetyve_ but I'm looking for confirmation.

Comment: Well, it was after [1744](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_a_Song_of_Sixpence), but I guess you knew that, given the example you chose.  Unless you were just going for the [drug reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/420_%28cannabis_culture%29).

Comment: I know in persian ,24 => بیست و چهار, like present day  English.

Comment: Careful here, note how a German would read 124: *einhundertvierundzwanzig*. The reading order is *mixed*. Also note the funny things the French do between 60 and 100.

Comment: It may be a Northern England thing (which is generally closer to Middle English), or less formal education — but my grandparents would say four and twenty.

Comment: @dmckee: 124 in german is einhundertvierundzwanzig.

Comment: @Malvolio, it's just that I learned German before English and, being French, I had always taken it for granted that English was "right" to use he same order as in French... till the day I poke my long nose into Old English.  To my great surprise I then found  another proof of the kinship between OE and German.  All in all, even though I found various (conflicting) explanations, it seems EL&U is the right place to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Alain : there are many positive things that can be said about the French culture and language -- I can't think of any but I'm sure they're out there -- however, the French number system leaves much to be desired. Consider *quatre vingt seize*, "four times twenty plus sixteen" or as we [non-batrachiophages](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24735/what-do-you-call-the-eating-of-frogs#answer-24738) would say, ninety-six.

Comment: @Malvolio, granted ! Given your pseudo, I think you will probably understand: "Ogni Scarrafone è bello a Mamma sua".  Exceptions is possibly what makes any language interesting.  French and English are probably on a par level in this respect.

Comment: Malvolio, just reading your comment confirms that I took  the right decision when I decided to come to this site. Continuez, s'il-vous-plaît!

Comment: @Alain, thank you very much.  That might be the most useful proverb I have ever read.  I'm going to email it to *my* momma in Tuscany.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question, but also a very complicated one.
It seems that the Jains, the believers in the old Indian religion Jainism, have invented the positional numeration ( at least they seem to have written the oldest known texts on the subject). Positional numeration  means describing all integers with just ten digits whose value varies according to their position in the written representation and, of course, this necessitates the use of a zero digit  which has no intrinsic value but functions as a placeholder.
The  information relevant to the question is that they enunciated numbers by starting with the digit for units, then that for dozens, etc. In other words, the  order opposite to the one used in contemporary English.

This does not answer the OP's question, but at least, since there have been deviations, we know from what they were deviations. I'm adding a [link](http://www.reunion.iufm.fr/dep/mathematiques/seminaires/resources/MSingh34.pdf) to a text (in French, unfortunately) by a historian who, interestingly for the users of this site, also evokes the Indian grammarian Panini. The point most relevant to our discussion is on page 199.